# Angular injected service losing data

Tags: angularjs, service

I have an Angular service I am using to store a user profile that can be used across controllers.  For example:

```
profile: {
            userId: 0,
            userName: '', 
}
```

The problem I have is that sometimes the profile in the injected service will be empty as if it was just created although on the previous page it had data.  It doesn't happen every time, but I can verify that the profile is empty when loading up the controller when it does happen.    Shouldn't the service be created as a singleton and have the same data when the next controller is created?

Comment: What do you mean by 'on the previous page'?  Are you browsing to a different URL?

Comment: Going to different url will cause a full page reload and as a result reinitialize angular. So when you go to a different page, is your page getting refreshed in the browser?

Comment: Please provide us with more code so we can see the behavior.

Comment: We navigate to a new view by using the location service such as:   $location.path('take-action');  Where the route is configured in our routeProvider config. This works for the most part except we get an empty service object occasionally.

Comment: I should also mention that our profile object is much more complex than that, it contains arrays of account objects.  I just simplified it here for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out another developer added a duplicate reference to the angular.js script and that was causing all sorts of strange behavior.  Removing the duplicate script reference solved the issue.